# Why does R allow new column creation via tail-slicing?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I create a data frame

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
```

Why does this code

```
df$z[c(1,2)] = c(7,8)
```

Produce this error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, z, value = c(7, 8)) : 
replacement has 2 rows, data has 3
```

While this code works?

```
df$z[c(2,3)] = c(7,8)
```

```
df
  a b  z
1 1 4 NA
2 2 5  7
3 3 6  8
```

Comment: Interestingly, `df$z[c(1,3)] <- 7:8` also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is coming from the `$<-.data.frame` function

```
> `$<-.data.frame`
function (x, name, value) 
{
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    nrows <- .row_names_info(x, 2L)
    if (!is.null(value)) {
        N <- NROW(value)
        if (N > nrows) 
            stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
...
```

i.e. the condition for `N > nrows` is satisfied

```
> NROW(c(7, 8))
[1] 2
> .row_names_info(df, 2L)
[1] 3
```

which is confirmed by `traceback()` on the error

```
> traceback()
3: stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
       "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
2: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, z, value = c(7, 8))
1: `$<-`(`*tmp*`, z, value = c(7, 8))
```

Comment: Very nice. I was tracing the wrong function `[<-.data.frame`!

Comment: Thanks! Is that a desirable behavior? 
Should the error trigger since the new vector is only partially defined (ie- the wrong length)?

Comment: @DBolta  Both cases should have returned error.  My understanding is that when the function was created, they may have thought for certain cases to return the error and didn't think about some unusual cases.  It is one of the reasons functions gets refined in subsequent releases..

Answer (score 6):

If the assignment is a vector, R appears to create the vector `z` to add to the `data.frame`, and that vector needs to have the same length as the number rows in the `data.frame`.

It's more clear what is happening if you work with a `list` object instead:

```
df <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
df$z1[1:2] <- 7:8
df$z2[2:3] <- 7:8
df$z3[c(1,3)] <- 7:8
df
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $z1
#> [1] 7 8
#> 
#> $z2
#> [1] NA  7  8
#> 
#> $z3
#> [1]  7 NA  8
data.frame(df)
#> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
data.frame(df[-3])
#>   a b z2 z3
#> 1 1 4 NA  7
#> 2 2 5  7 NA
#> 3 3 6  8  8
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it's the `$<-.data.frame` method and its error message, but here we have `N < nrows`, not `N > nrows` as @akrun claims.    Everying else is correct of course, it's just rather this part of the code (further below in the function body) that signals the error  (lines 1195ff in the source `<R>/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R`):

```
        if (N < nrows)
            if (N > 0L && (nrows %% N == 0L) && length(dim(value)) <= 1L)
                value <- rep(value, length.out = nrows)
            else
                stop(sprintf(ngettext(N,
                                      "replacement has %d row, data has %d",
                                      "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"),
                             N, nrows), domain = NA)
```

Note that this also shows in which cases such replacement does *not* signal an error, namely when `nrows` is a multiple of `N`, i.e, if you had 4 rows instead of 3, then recycling would happen.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one remark, if you use this syntaxe it works :

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                b=c(4, 5, 6, 6))

df[c(2, 3), 3] <- 1
```

It appears that if you use `df$something`, you need to instanciate the last row.

```
df$z[4] <- 1 # works
```

But :

```
df$z[1/2/3] <- 1 # do not works
```

However, if you do it in two steps it works :

```
df$z <- 1
df$z[1/2/3] <- 1
```

So I have no good answer but it is maybe one step to the answer. Akrun gives the answer.

Comment: Per akrun's comment, this is on an even different function with different behaviors...
`[<-.data.frame`